# Как сделать в главном меню игры на модели монитора кнопки unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

такой вопрос у меня есть модель монитора в unreal engine 4 и мне надо сделать так что-бы на этом мониторе были кнопки и текст, кнопки должны быть рабочие (т.е нажал на кнопку и появилась какая-нибудь надпись на мониторе), идеи нету как такое можно сделать блюпринтами, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С помощью 3D Widget я смог сделать то, что хотел